# `shouldFail` vs. `thrown`

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit, spock

In investigating Groovy and Spock testing, I have run across two ways of catching exceptions:  `shouldFail` and `thrown`.

Is there a real difference between these two ways of asserting against exceptions? It looks like `shouldFail` is more JUnit-ish and `thrown` is more Spock, but other than this I can't find any descriptions of the difference or best practices between them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The Spock way is `thrown`. The `GroovyTestCase` way is `shouldFail`. You can't use the latter with Spock.

Comment: Actually, I am using the latter with Spock.

Comment: Then you are probably using `GroovyAssert#shouldFail`. (Why do you leave us guessing?) I don't see the point in using this with Spock.

Answer (score 0):

If I only care the exception is thrown, I tend to use

```
thrown(SomeException)
```

If I want to check some property of the exception, I tend to use

```
SomeException ex = thrown()
```

Not sure what you mean by should fail